# Replace classname into CSS with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I've got several class names and they are all 99% identical - except the background image. The classname always matches the image filename:

**Example (see .icon_hero_rank-19):**

```
.brawler .rank.icon_hero_rank-19 {
    background-image: url("/images/ranks/icon_hero_rank-19.png");
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "BrawlStarsDeputy";
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**The question:**

So is there a way to reuse the class name as variable in my CSS or what do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend that you don't use the image filename as the classname.

Comment: Why not @Alohci?

Comment: Because it misses the point of classes. Classes are there to say "these elements belong to the same class (or category, group, collection, kind-of-thing, if you prefer)". It's unlikely you'll have multiple elements that form a group of any kind based on the image filename.

Answer (score 1):

One can use predefined variable names for the selectors and for the CSS properties like this:

```
$icon-list: (
    icon_hero_rank-00,
    icon_hero_rank-19
);

@each $icon in $icon-list {
    .brawler .rank.#{$icon}{
        background-image: url("/images/ranks/#{$icon}.png");
        position: absolute;
        top: 85%;
        left: 0;
        width: 40px;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        background-size: contain;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family: "BrawlStarsDeputy";
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        text-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use for loop

### [Take a look at this](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d7b099372c6fbef783a9184136900a4d)

```
$string-template: "icon_hero_rank-";


$start: 0;

@for $i from 1 through 8 {


.brawler .rank.#{$string-template}#{$i+$start} {
    background-image: url("/images/ranks/#{$string-template}#{$i+$start}.png");
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "BrawlStarsDeputy";
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    z-index: 10;
}



}
```

Comment: That probably wouldn't work because I need 00 - 19 , but a nice idea, upvoted!

Comment: Np. I too like @kentor 's solution better  :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer your already posted, kentor, you could considerably condense your compiled CSS by using attribute selectors to set all the shared styles only one time and then set the background image in the `@each` function.

```
.brawler div[class*="icon_hero_"].rank {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "BrawlStarsDeputy";
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    z-index: 10;
}

$icon-list: (
    rank-00,
    rank-19
);

@each $icon in $icon-list {
    .brawler div[class$="#{$icon}"].rank{
        background-image: url("/images/ranks/#{$icon}.png");
    }
}
```

That way, you don't end up with the shared styles repeated a bunch of times in your stylesheet.